# New Private Key and provisioning profile for an iphone app update

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I use an external developer for a new version of my iphone app. Now, as the release is approaching, in order to create the final appstore build, he asked me for an updated provisioning profile. The existing I had, was expired so I created a new one from Provisioning Portal - Provisioning - Development (Tab) and send it to him.

Problem is that now he informed me that I had to send him a new .p12 file because the newly attached provisioning profile no longer matches the private key he had on file. I've read [this tutorial](https://appmakr.zendesk.com/entries/175966-how-to-create-and-upload-your-private-key-p12-into-your-appmakr-developer-account) and I have some questions.

From the Certificates- Distribution tab, I have a certificate ready for download, which must have been created same day with the new provisioning profile and it expires next year so I guess I don't have anything to do here.

So I want to ask how to create this private key file. I opened keychain access and I see that there is an iphone distribution keychain which is expiring in one year but it has a red color sentence saying "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". If I export this and give it to the developer, is it ok ?

Thanks
Kostas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p12 file is used to create the Certificate Signing Request, which is what you uploaded to the developer portal when you requested your distribution certificate. If you have not changed systems or deleted things it should be in your keychain.

Open Keychain Access, navigate to My Certificates, find your distribution certificate, expand the arrow to show the private key attached to it. Then right click on the private key and choose export, this is the file your developer needs.

Here is a screenshot showing what it should look like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think it's ok